# Set Min height to start on new page for sub report

Tags: java, jasper-reports, height, subreport, dynamic-reports

I have create a report using dynamic report that contains multiple sub reports. What I need is add sub report to current page if and only if it has space for at least one row of detail section of sub report.
Is there any option to set min height to start on new page for sub report ?

Please refer the following images.

[image: First Page]

[image: Second Page]

Comment: Use a group also with "dummy" expression then set min-height on group.

Comment: I tried it already. It didn't work.

Comment: Only the column values is moved to next page if we use group with min height, the column title still get printed on the first page.

Comment: is the columnHeader in subreport or is outside?

Comment: Column header is also in subreport. `HorizontalColumnGridListBuilder` which is used to create title group also added in sub report.

Comment: You need the group above the subreport, then indicate min-height of that group.